# commons-httpclient-3.1 vs (httpclient-4.5.13 and httpcore-4.4.13)

Tags: java

what is the history of commons-httpclient-3.1, My application has all the three commons-httpclient-3.1 , httpclient-4.5.13 , httpcore-4.4.13. So can I remove commons-httpclient-3.1 ?
Can they be used interchangeably? What is the purpose of these 3 jars?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the history of commons-httpclient-3.1

HttpClient 3.x is a legacy project.  It has been superseded by the HttpClient subproject of HttpComponents 4.x; see https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/

> Can they be used interchangeably?

No.  HttpClient 3.x APIs and HttpClient 4.x APIs are not directly compatible.  They are a different set of classes in different packages.

> What is the purpose of these 3 jars?

- `commons-httpclient-3.1` is a HttpClient 3.x implementation.
- `httpclient-4.x` and `httpcore-4.x` together are the components of the HttpClient 4.x implementation.

(It looks you have different versions of the 4.x JARs, which might cause problems.)

> So can I remove commons-httpclient-3.1 ?

It depends.  It is plausible that different parts of your application code-base use both HttpClient 3.x and HttpClient 4.x.  If they do, then you cannot remove `commons-httpclient-3.1` ... unless you are prepared to rework those parts of the application (and / or its dependencies) that use the 3.x APIs.